# override view from plugin NopCommerce 4.3

Tags: c#, content-management-system, nopcommerce

I want to override view of shipping method page. I try all variants and nothing work.
Help me please. Thank in advance

Answer (score 3):

To overwrite a View in NopCommerce you first need to copy the *.cshtml* file you want to change into your plugin and do the modifications. Don't forget to set this file as Content and set the *Copy to Output Directory* property to Copy if Newer or Copy Always.

After that you also have to implement the *IViewLocationExpander* interface in your plugin. It should look something like this.

```
public class MyViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
   public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
   {
      if(context.ViewName == "ViewToOverwrite")
      {
         viewLocations = new[] { "PathToMyCustomView" }.Concat(viewLocations);
      }

      return viewLocations;
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
       return;
    }
}
```

The last step is to register your custom view expander for the plugin.
You can do this by implementing the *INopStartup* interface in your plugin. It should look something like this.

```
public class MyStartup : INopStartup
{
   public int Order => int.MaxValue;

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
   {
   }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
      {
         options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new MyViewLocationExpander());
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, implement ViewLocaionExpander in your plugin.
This will override your view and it will render from plugin's view

Answer (score -1):

Hi I used similar solution to solve this problem.
In your RouteProvider.cs

```
public partial class RouteProvider : IRouteProvider
   {
    public void RegisterRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpointRouteBuilder)
        {
               endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute("RedirectPdfPackagingSlip",
                    "Admin/yourController/yourAction",
                    new { controller = "Order", action = "PdfPackagingSlip" });
        }
    }
```

and to go back to the original method you can use in the controller

```
  if (order.ShippingRateComputationMethodSystemName != "your shipping method SystemName")
            return Redirect("~/Admin/Order/PdfPackagingSlip?shipmentId=" + ShipmentId);
```

I hope this helped